# How does useState updates the component?

Tags: reactjs

At the beginning I thought that the react component's function body somehow listens to anything what changes inside, and that's why it updates. But then I've tried to set up an interval, which changes a variable inside the function's body, but it didn't updated.

A good question is that how custom hooks work, as it's just a function, which has some values and return them, but able to update a functional component.

So basically the question is: how useState communicates with it's parent function, to make it update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the two important rules of react hooks states that 'Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions'. This rule needs to be followed because React relies on the order in which the hooks are called to determine which hook call belongs to which state/component. Find explanation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)

Now answering your main query- You have mentioned 'parent function'. Custom hooks are never child functions to the components. If it would be so, we would be violating the rule of hooks as it will be the case of calling the hooks in nested function. Custom hooks are just independent functions where we call useState(or any hook) and React just keeps track of that state and associates it with the appropriate component using the order in which it was called. For detailed explanation see Ryan Florence talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jWS7cCuUXw)

Answer (score 0):

`useState` returns an array with two elements. The first element is the current value, the second element is a method that you can use to update the value. Using this method to update the value triggers a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Here is theory how it works. In old ages there were class components. Class components have function called setState. That function change component state and also say to engine: "Hey mate this component have changed its data. Please rerender that component and its subtree." Nowadays we have hook function setState. It works kinda similiar, but instead of having setState function we have setter and getter function for value. When setter is called react knows that it belongs to exact component and rerender. It's simplified but i hope that helps.

Comment: How does react know that a hook belongs to which component? What about custom hooks? They can belong to multiple components.